# How to get the "value" of a upload input with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, upload

I know that this sends stuff to a php file and gets stuff returned from the php file as javascript:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "phpfile",
   cache: false,
   data: datahere,
   dataType: "script"
 });
```

But... suppose "datahere" is a file from a input file element. How am I supposed to get the value or data from that upload input file element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at these plugins: [7 trusted ajax file upload plugins using jquery](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/)

Those are some AJAX file upload plugins. They might be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "phpfile",
   cache: false,
   data: $('.thisInput').val(),
   dataType: "script"
 });
```

Comment: thanks for yuor reply imoda, but that will only send the url of the file... not the actual file itself

Comment: That's all you need to handle the form.